# Sqlite3 python compare a row for user and password

Tags: python, sqlite

I am currently working on a project with a login a page. What I want to do is first compare if the username exits in the database and after that the password. This is for separate error handling for username and password. But my code crashes after I execute the login. I tried comparing both username and password at the same time and I encountered no errors. This is the code:

```
def proflog(self):
    user = self.line_user.text()
    password = self.line_pass.text()

    conn = sqlite3.connect("users.db")
    use = conn.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE USERS = ?",(user))
    if(len(use.fetchall())>0):
            passw = conn.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE PASS = ?", (password))
            if (len(passw.fetchall()>0)):
                        gotowin(prof,log)
            else:
                    print("Wrong Password")

   else:
           print("Wrong username")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(user)` evaluates to `user` in Python; however, `sqlite` requires a list or tuple object. Therefore, you need to add a comma to the tuple:

```
use = conn.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE USERS = ?",(user,))
...
passw = conn.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE PASS = ?", (password,))
```

Comment: The program still crashes even though I've done that. Thank you for reply.